# Pitfalls of using shell scripts to wrap a program?

Tags: bash

Consider I have a program that needs an environment set. It is in Perl and I want to modify the environment (to search for libraries a special spot).

Every time I mess with the the standard way to do things in UNIX I pay a heavy price and I pay a penalty in flexibility.

I know that by using a simple shell script I will inject an additional process into the process tree. Any process accessing its own process tree might be thrown for a little bit of a loop.

Anything recursive to a nontrivial way would need to defend against multiple expansions of the environment.

Anything resembling being in a pipe of programs (or closing and opening `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, or `STDERR`) is my biggest area of concern.

What am I doing to myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing to myself?

Getting yourself all het up over nothing?

Wrapping a program in a shell script in order to set up the environment is actually quite standard and the risk is pretty minimal unless you're trying to do something *really* weird.

If you're really concerned about having one more process around — and UNIX processes are very cheap, by design — then use the `exec` keyword, which instead of forking a new process, simply exec's a new executable in place of the current one.  So, where you might have had

```
#!/bin/bash -
FOO=hello
PATH=/my/special/path:${PATH}
perl myprog.pl
```

You'd just say

```
#!/bin/bash -
FOO=hello
PATH=/my/special/path:${PATH}
exec perl myprog.pl
```

and the spare process goes away.

This trick, however, is almost never worth the bother; the one counter-example is that if you can't change your default shell, it's useful to say

```
$ exec zsh
```

in place of just running the shell, because then you get the expected behavior for process control and so forth.